# React-native : response of fetch impossible to treat

Tags: ajax, react-native, state, fetch, setstate

Still learning on RN... I'm trying to use `fetch()` in react-native to get a **specific data from my server**, before **opening a webpage** in smartphone's browser.
Here is what I wrote :

```
openLink = () => {       //Communicate to the server to get an unique key_id
  this.state = {urlKey: 'text'}; //Initial state


  var params = {
      // Some params send by POST to authenticate the request...
  };

  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var k in params) {
      formData.append(k, params[k]);
  }
      fetch(Constants.URL.root+"mobile/authorize_view", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
               },
                body: formData
              })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({urlKey:responseJson.document_key}); //Getting the response, and changing the initial state (was 'text' previously)
          })
          .done();

  var urlString = Constants.URL.upload + '/' + this.state.urlKey; // !!Problem : opening in browser with this.state.urlKey = text, and not document_key!!
  Linking.canOpenURL(urlString).then(supported => {
    if (supported) {
      Linking.openURL(urlString);
    } else {
      console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + this.props.url);
    }
  });
}
```

Actually, as you can see, I ask for a **specific key to my server** (**urlKey**, that is returned in a JSON Object : responseJson.document_key).

*Everything is **running well** in server's part, cause I put this generated document_key in my Database, and I can see it is put correctly.*

The problem is in React-native part : the browser opens a webpage with `this.state.urlKey` as `**text**` which is the **initial state** that the function `fetch` should have turned into the document_key sent by server...
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch statement is asynchronous. Meaning when you call fetch then next line of execution not necessary the `.then` but is
 `var urlString = Constants.URL.upload + '/' + this.state.urlKey;`

Note by this stage if `.then` isnt complete fetching the data your `this.state.document_key` will not be populated. Hence why you see the error

Instead move that code in the  final `then` e.g:

```
openLink = () => {       //Communicate to the server to get an unique key_id
  this.state = {urlKey: 'text'}; //Initial state


  var params = {
      // Some params send by POST to authenticate the request...
  };

  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var k in params) {
      formData.append(k, params[k]);
  }
      fetch(Constants.URL.root+"mobile/authorize_view", {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
               },
                body: formData
              })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({urlKey:responseJson.document_key}); //Getting the response, and changing the initial state (was 'text' previously)
              //moved inside then
              var urlString = Constants.URL.upload + '/' + this.state.urlKey; // !!Problem : opening in browser with this.state.urlKey = text, and not document_key!!
              Linking.canOpenURL(urlString).then(supported => {
                if (supported) {
                  Linking.openURL(urlString);
                } else {
                  console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + this.props.url);
                }
              });
          })
          .done();
}
```